# sails can't find layout.jade

Tags: node.js, pug, sails.js

I am starting to learn Sails (0.9.7, node 0.10.16) and running through the sailscasts episodes. I am also trying to use jade as I do so. Where I am stuck now is that sails is not finding views/layout.jade. I backed out all the jade stuff and redid with ejs and sails is not finding views/layout.ejs.

As a last resort, I cloned activtyoverlord (the sailscasts app) and when I sails lift activityoverlord does not find its views/layout.ejs.

Any suggests as to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: please post a link to your repo and I'll take a look.

Comment: Thank you for looking. It's at https://github.com/frpaulas/demo

Comment: @JohnGalt who are you man?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a jade user, however, I think you need to put `extends ../layout` at the top of your `index.jade` file to use `layout.jade`.

Also, I think both the `layout.jade` and `index.jade` have tabs and spaces (I don't think you can use both).  I took out the tabs and added spaces in your `layout.ejs` file.

I created a project from scratch, changed engine to `jade` in `config/views.js` but left `layout` to the default value.

Also, I used these tags in layout.jade:

```
 // SCRIPTS
 // SCRIPTS END
```

and

```
 // STYLES   
 // STYLE END
```

Grunt then puts the appropriate paths for javascript and styles in your layout file.  I couldn't get `index.jade` into the `layout.jade` but I don't know enough about jade to determine what's wrong.

Here's a link to the repo I made: https://github.com/irlnathan/sails-answers-jade

Comment: Brilliant! I completely missed the extends ../layout bit. And I can't believe I have been bitten again by the space/tab bug (grr). Thank you

Comment: To get index.jade into layout.jade you need to add a block in index.jade. In this case "block body" to match up with what you have in layout.jade.

Comment: Also, the asset handling doesn't work quite right if you use tabs for indentation, it only indents the link/script tags correctly in jade if you are using spaces.  I call this a bug, the spaces are better than tabs tabs crusaders of the internet might call this a feature.