# How to make the linker in Sails js work with Jade?

Tags: pug, sails.js

I have followed the instructions [here](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/assets) yet I couldn't get the linker to work with Jade. If, however I use ejs instead, it does work (exactly the same app, apart from the jade/ejs files of course). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm assuming you have done the following:

- Created a new project with linker and jade as template

  ```
  sails new <project-name> --template=jade --linker
  ```
- you manually added jade

  ```
  cd <project-name>
  npm install jade --save
  ```
- (optionally) removed the dependency to ejb in the package.json file.

Is that correct?

In that case, I've received a warn that says:

```
warn: Automatic asset linking is not implemented for the `jade` view engine at this time. You must modify the Gruntfile yourself for this feature to work.
```

This looks like an old and outdated message, as I looked to the grunt file and everything look like it was prepared for linking to jade.

So then, I've changed the layout.jade file in the views folder to:

- Remove   script(src="/js/sails.io.js")
- and add the placeholders to inject:

  ```
  // SCRIPTS
  // SCRIPTS END
  // STYLES
  // STYLES END
  ```

Then I made a "sails lift" and the scripts in the javascript files in the public/linker/js folder were injected.

BTW: I'm using sails v0.9.9

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Being new to sails and jade i found the following link helpful.  Turns out you need to go into config > views.js & then change the "engine:" from saying 'ejs' to 'jade'

After doing this you'll have to also install jade as a dependency:

```
npm install jade --save
```

[sails can't find layout.jade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20473326/sails-cant-find-layout-jade)